# Flutter: it it possible to measure the similarity percentage between a word's proper pronunciation and the player's pronunciation?

Tags: flutter, dart, speech-recognition, game-development, speech

I am creating a simple game application that uses speech recognition. In the game, the player has to pronounce the word and then the system will evaluate or process if the player's word pronunciation is correct. If they are correct, the system will print 100%, and if they're right but needs some improvement in pronounciation, they will still get a percentage below 100%. For the speech recognition, I am using the SpeechtoText package.

The game will have different levels and in each level, there are different words to be pronounced. At the end of the game, the system will calculate the accumulated percentage score of the player and will print if the player needs some improvement on their pronunciation skills.

Is there any solution for this issue? any advice please?

So far, I am still trying to find any available API that I can use. Though, I am not sure the thorough step on how am I going to implement this. Any advices, and tips will be much appreciated.

Comment: Ah - this is challenging from a socio-linguistic perspective. What is the "proper" pronunciation of a word? Just because someone uses different pronunciation from another person doesn't mean their pronunciation is "wrong". Australian and American accents sound very different - but neither is "wrong". I say "PRO-ject", you say "pro-JECT" - who is wrong?